# MS Managament Studio 17.6, не создаёт таблицу

Tags: sql, sql-server

Итак: создаю обычную БД(стандартные настройки) через графический режим(не запросами). Создаю простенький запрос, где пишу, допустим, следующий код:

```
create table M (Id bigint identity primary key, [name] nvarchar(25))
```

Запрос выполняется без ошибок, всё прекрасно. Но таблица не создаётся. *use* указывал, БД в раскрывающемся списке слева выбирал, БД и раздел таблицы обновлял. Таблицы нет. И, как понятно уже, так с любой таблицей. Что можно сделать с этой проблемой?

Comment: А что дает запрос select * from M?

Comment: @msi *Выполнение команд успешно завершено*, но таблица не высветилась + подчеркнул M(первый запрос я закомментировал)

Comment: скрин можете показать?

Comment: @msi разумеется: http://i-fotki.info/23/a2b329e20022000aa96b4c351533e9ca6dac37305742465.jpg.html

Comment: Такое впечатление, что вы не ту команду выполняете - анализ (ctrl-F5) вместо выполнить (F5).

Comment: @msi всё так и было...Я помогал знакомой, а она привыкла к VS, там ведь это запуск приложения без отладки:) Спасибо

Comment: Тогда это будет ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое впечатление, что вы не ту команду выполняете - анализ (ctrl-F5) вместо выполнить (F5).